# why is the secret not the same for both parties?

Tags: node.js, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to understand how the diffie hellman key exchange works and wrote a simple node.js program to make a test:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

//create a public & private key for alice
var Alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(512);
Alice.generateKeys();

//create a public & private key for bob
var Bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(512);
Bob.generateKeys();

//let bob and alice compute the shared secret
console.log(Alice.computeSecret(Bob.getPublicKey()).toString("hex"));
console.log(Bob.computeSecret(Alice.getPublicKey()).toString("hex"));
```

If i understood the right graphics on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) wikipedia article right, then both secrets should be the same. But they never are, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well I already found the solution:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var prime = crypto.createDiffieHellman(512).getPrime();

//create a public & private key for alice
var Alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(prime);
Alice.generateKeys();

//create a public & private key for bob
var Bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(prime);
Bob.generateKeys();

//let bob and alice compute the shared secret
console.log(Alice.computeSecret(Bob.getPublicKey()).toString("hex"));
console.log(Bob.computeSecret(Alice.getPublicKey()).toString("hex"));
```

Comment: how i can encrypt and decrypt messages using this keys? can you please explain

Comment: you can use createCipher/createDecipher for en/decoding and use the shared secred as 'password'

Comment: i want to encrypt alice publickey and decrypt using private key. is this possible using D-H algorithm or any other algorithm does this job. Please suggest me.